# Trouble with QSerialPort use in custom library

Tags: c++, qt, lua, serial-port

I'm trying to make a lua package using the [Lua C API](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3) and [LuaBridge](https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge), and I need to send data through a serial port, thus the use of Qt's [QSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html).

The binding works fine, that is, I can use the class I registered with Lua in my scripts. However, every time I use QSerialPort::write, Qt prints tha following warning:

```
QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
```

I have not declared a QCoreApplication, and I do not know where I should declare it since a library doesn't have a main() function.

The closest thing I have to an entry point is

```
int luaopen_my_io_lib(lua_State *L);
```

which registers my class to Lua.

The QSerialPort is used as a member of the class I register, and constructed without a parent QObject.

How can I fix this?

[EDIT] here is the code that triggers the warning:

```
bool SerialIO::write(std::string data) {
    m_port.write(data.c_str());
    return m_port.waitForBytesWritten(100);
}
```

where m_port is a QSerialPort.

I think I should be able to fix it by starting a new QThread, but that would be a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: Can you add some Qt code (I dont have any experience with lua sorry). What is the lua_State? Is it Qt class which you are providing for lua? The warning is printed when you call QTimer::start from different thread. I dont know if QSerialPort is using QTimer in it(you can check your code).. if it does and lua is running your classes in separate threads somehow (just shot in the dark) then this creates the problem.

Comment: lua_State is simply a handle for interfacing with lua. I've modified the post to show where the warning is displayed.

Comment: May be you can just use other serial port library (e.g. librs232)? If you run lua interpretator (e.g. lua.exe) then it does not run thread as `QThread` so you can write your own interpretator based on QT.